# Auto grab ID function?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I have two tables that I am working with.

The first is set up something like these tables

```
Destination

IDDestination    Name        IDCity  IDState
1              Scottsdale     3        4
2                Miami        5        7
```

and

```
Destinations_Citites

IDDestinationCity    IDDestination    IDCity
1                      1               3
2                      2               5
```

Now with my plugin I have an add a new destination button which adds a new destination with its `Name`, `IDCity` and `IDState` filled out by the user and the `IDDestination` is automatically generated.

So what I want to figure out how to do is to grab that automatically generated `IDDestination` # and enter it into the `Destinations_Cities` table with out having the user do anything else.

Basically how can I insert the automatically generated `IDDEstination` that was just created and throw it into my other table without the user having to add it themselves.

Here is the code I am using to Insert and Update for my add destinations button

```
if(isset($_POST['Add_Destination'])) {
    $idstate = $_POST['idstate1'];
    $idcity = $_POST['idcity'];
    $name = $_POST['addname'];
    $SQL="INSERT INTO destination (name, IDCity, IDState) VALUES ('". $name ."','". $idcity ."','". $idstate ."')";
    $SQL1="UPDATE city SET is_active='1' WHERE IDCity='$idcity'";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());
    $result1=mysql_query($SQL1) or die (mysql_error());
    print $SQL;
    print $SQL1;
}
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injections. `POST ?idcity=' OR 1 = 1 --` would update *all* cities. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Where did you learn to use `mysql_query`? We must endeavour to update that resource as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the most recent auto-increment id generated during your session:

```
$dest_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Refer to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

---

Not exactly about your question, but I echo the comment above that you should protect your queries from SQL injection vulnerabilities. Don't copy PHP variables into SQL strings unless you have made sure the variables are made safe.

- If a variable is supposed to be an integer, use `(int)` to cast it to an integer as you read it.
- For string values, use escaping provided by the MySQL API.

Also, there's no need to do all the `.` concatenation if you're just putting simple variables inside PHP strings. There's no need in SQL to put quotes around integer literals.

Here's an example:

```
if(isset($_POST['Add_Destination'])) {
    $idstate = (int) $_POST['idstate1'];
    $idcity = (int) $_POST['idcity'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addname']);
    $SQL="INSERT INTO destination (name, IDCity, IDState) 
        VALUES ('$name', $idcity, $idstate)";
    $dest_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $SQL1="UPDATE city SET is_active='1' WHERE IDCity='$idcity'";
    . . .
```

If you convert your code to use PDO, you can use SQL query parameters, in which case you wouldn't need to worry about escaping and such.